# Login with post with Alamofire not works

Tags: swift, alamofire

Hello people I'm trying to this post with Alamofire, but I failed, when I try this post with postman, I've got a successful message.

```
fetch("urlofMyServer", {
    credentials: "include",
    method: "POST",
    body: new URLSearchParams({
      "identity": "example@mail.com",
      "credential": "hello123",
      "type": "normal_user",
    }) // content-type has to be application/x-www-form-urlencoded
}).then(() => console.log("success"));
```

this is my code with Alamofire, what I'm wrong?

```
public func makeLogin(param: [String:String], completion: @escaping ((Bool?) -> Void)){
        let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        ]
        AF.request(endPoints.login.login, method: .post, parameters: param, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers, interceptor: nil).responseJSON { (response) in
            if let status = response.response?.statusCode{
                do {
                    let result = try response.result.get()
                    if let data = result as? [String:String]{
                        print(data)
                        completion(true)
                    }
                } catch{
                    completion(false)
                }
            }else{
                completion(false)
            }
        }
    }
```

My param are:

```
let info = [
     "identity" : "example@mail.com",
     "credential": "hello124",
     "type" : "normal_user"
] as! [String:String]
```

and my headers are:

```
let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
     "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
]
```

[image: body postman]
[image: headers postman]
[image: params postman]

I'm using Alamofire 5 and swift 5, repeat, with postman I got a successful message, but with Alamofire the message was: `Missing required field: identity.`

Comment: share a screenshot of postman to show how you send the params

Comment: @KeshuR. I have added some screenshots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing to `URLEncoding.default`

Comment: thanks, I used URLEncoding.httpBody and works, but also I used your answer and works,

Answer (score 0):

just change encoding: `JSONEncoding.default` to `URLEncoding.httpBody` and you are good to go!

```
AF.request(endPoints.login.login, method: .post, parameters: param, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: headers, interceptor: nil).responseJSON { (response) in
```

Comment: thanks, but with `String.Encoding.utf8` I got this message "Argument type 'String.Encoding' does not conform to expected type 'ParameterEncoding'", so, I change your suggest to `URLEncoding.httpBody` and now works. Thanks

Comment: @abrahamTrus cool. I have updated the answer for future visitors :)